# Android ListView items: image and text too small

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm working on a ListView where each item has an image and some text.  On my older phone, HTC Evo 4G, things came up exactly as expected.  Image is nicely sized and text looks fine.  Then I loaded the same app on my new phone, HTC One, and the images are so tiny they are useless.  I know the HTC One has a significantly higher resolution, but I cannot figure out how to make each item in the ListView larger.

I'm not sure what to post, but I think the layout xml files are the issue.

Here's activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip" android:background="#669900">

    <!--
      Use layout_weight to stretch the EditText and compress the button.
      To avoid text wrap, the editable text is forced to occupy only one
      line
    -->
    <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:typeface="normal"
      android:layout_weight="1" android:lines="1" android:ellipsize="middle"
      android:hint="@string/hint" android:id="@+id/search_key" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:maxLines="1"></EditText>

    <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_search" android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:layout_weight="0" android:id="@+id/btn_ok" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageButton>

</LinearLayout>
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tweet_header" 
    android:gravity="right" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:paddingRight="4dp" 
    android:background="#99cc33" android:textColor="#000000" android:textSize="21dp"></TextView>


<ListView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tweet_list"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the ListView is made up of this item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/itemImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/created_at"
    android:text="now" 
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_below="@id/itemImage"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemURL"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="itemURL"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So the app does this:  It taps ebay for car data and presents the search results as line 1 with a picture, line 2 with the ebay item title.  A hidden value is the URL so users can tap the ListView line and launch a web browser.

Comment: Could we have your code please?

Comment: Is this question re-opened now?

Comment: Moderators : I am asking for this question to be re-opened.  Thank you.

Comment: Your question still does not contain what you've tried so far and why those attempts didn't work.

Comment: I've tried fiddling with the layout_width and layout_height values, but I don't see any difference.  Clearly I'm a novice in the use of layouts.

Comment: I'm hoping someone will read my layout xml files and spot the issue.  The code itself does not set any of these values.  I connect the results of a web query into the ListView and it just works.

Comment: I would post a screenshot, but I lack the reputation points to allow it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the wrap_content setting for the ImageView's layout_width and layout_height are the issue.  When I switched that to numerical values, suddenly I saw it change size.  Finally setting it to 100dp made the images viewable.

As an aside, I had a terrible time with ADS and the emulator.  It consistently failed to re-load my updated app.  Often complaining about the Package Manager and suggesting the some process was running.  I little idea what was running and how to fix it.  When I switched to loading the app straight to the phone, then it worked fine.

So, I think now I need to create a system that is proportional, and takes in to consideration the displaying devices resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the Relative Layout width being wrap_content. Try changing that to match parent. then you would not have to go thru this ordeal